# HibernateUtil initializig error on the webserver

Tags: hibernate

I hav a webserver and when I try to use the hibernate util I get an excpetion (returned to the client):

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soapenv:Server' faultstring: 'Could not initialize class com.test.data.HibernateUtil' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@4054db90
```

It worked fine on my local pc. How can I know what is the reason for it?

```
I have the following code:
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
//            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Really really needs help with this... can supply any code needed.

I have updated the HibernateUtil without the try/catch, now I get the exact excpeion:

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soapenv:Server' faultstring: 'org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@4054b2c0
```

But the jar is deployed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience with static block to initialize sessionFactory your issue lies in this line of code:

```
sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Looks like it is not able to get the datasource while building the sessionFactory.

Can you log the exception uncomment this line and see whats being printed:

```
 System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
```

Comment: How can I see this log in the hosting? Will try to get the ex into the client

Comment: I get the following: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found. Why....?

Comment: Look into the jar which was deployed and see if you have this file inside the jar or not, usually should be present under src folder

Comment: Well... It is not - how should I add it?

Comment: I am not sure how you built your jar, ANT ? You will have to rebuild it and ensure that hibernate.cfg is added in your jar file.

Comment: Thanks a lot - it was very helpful  -  problem was I have selected include .class files only when creating the .arr

Comment: Now I get the following.... ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken [from com.test.data.Object r where r.name LIKE '%%' and r.complete=true].. Please 0 another help, It never finish